# Controling popup open and close focus

Tags: wpf, popup, focus, focusmanager

I have a popup which contains multiple elements, a list view, a text box and a button. These are operating fine, and if you use the button to close the popup it works as well, but when i tried to make the popup close when it lost focus, it closed when i clicked an element in the listview. Is there any way around this? Is the FocusManager property the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the stayopen property of the popup control in you code. If it is not working please post your code.

Comment: StaysOpen is dependent on focus, its really just a re-implementation of what i have already done. The code is pretty dependent, working on a sample app

Answer (score 2):

Set **FocusManager.IsFocusScope = True** on your Popup element, so it keep focus as long as one of his children has it.

Comment: If i set the focusmanager.IsFocusScope to true, the popup never closes. This confused me... I thought that since the popup was part of a data template maybe it thought the entire application was its child :P

Comment: @micael Bergerron FocusManager.IsFocusScope="true" is done then also it gets closed. My popup control contains one user control which contains AutoCompleteBox having dropdown behaviour. If I select any element from dropdown the popup gets closed

Answer (score 1):

You should just set the StaysOpen property on your popup like this:

```
<Popup StaysOpen="True">
...
</Popup>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen.aspx